# ELB health check fail AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, gateway

My ELB health check fails all the time but cannot figure it why (502 bad gateway).

I have a cluster (ECS) with a service that runs at least one task (Fargate) which is a Node API listening on port 3000 & 3001 (3000 for http & 3001 for https since I cannot use port below 1024).

I have an Elastic Load Balancer (application) that is listening on port 80. It forwards the trafic on a target group with protocol port 3000.

This target group has as target type: ip address since I use fargate and not EC2 for my tasks.
So when a task is turning on, I correctly see the private IP of the task registering into the target group.

My health route is server_ip_address/health and it returns a classic 200 status code. This route works well because I tried it directly from the public ip address of the task (quickly before it stopped because of the health check failing) and it returns a 200. I also tried it through the ELB dns name (so my-elb.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/health) and it worked well as well so I don't understand why the health check fail.

Anyone know what I missed ?

Comment: Have you checked the health check settings? Its possible to be on a different port for the health check vs the instance traffic being routed to. Could you share the health check settings

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Sure here is a screenshot of my health check settings on the target group: https://imgur.com/ZMIIk62

Comment: Here are the targets of the target group: https://imgur.com/WFVcKca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshot of your targets in the target group it is showing the port as 80, this means that the load balancer (and health check) will be attempting to connect to the Fargate container on port 80.

You mentioned that it should be served from port 3000, therefore you will need to ensure that the target group is listening on port 3000 instead. Once this is in place, assuming that the security group of the host allows inbound access the 502 error should go away.

To be clear the listener port is what port the client connects to, whereas the target port is the port the load balancer connects to your target on.

Comment: I am not sure to understand.

According to the doc "By default, a load balancer routes requests to its targets using the protocol and port number that you specified when you created the target group. Alternatively, you can override the port used for routing traffic to a target when you register it with the target group."

That's what I did when I created the target group, I've set the port as 3000 (as you can see on the screens). So theoretically my load balancer should redirect traffic to the target group on port 3000 right ?

Comment: Hi, I mean if you look at your screenshot: https://imgur.com/WFVcKca the targets are registered to port 80. If you adjust to 3000 assuming the security group allows for it this should work for you

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for you time !
Ok I understand, the problem is that I don't decide the port the targets are registering on. Targets are registering automatically when a new task is launching with the private IP of the task. When I create a new service in my cluster I can decide which load balancer and which target group it will use so I select my load balancer and my target group but I still can't decide the port. Maybe this is the problem? I include a screenshot of this step so you can see: https://imgur.com/a/462fr0m

Comment: These will be the port mappings in your Fargate task I believe? Have you perhaps mapped 80:80 rather than 3000:3000?

Comment: That's it! I mapped port 80 and 443 in the task definition instead of 3000 & 3001. I misunderstood that part when I created the task definition. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Haha, no problem glad your problem is now resolved :)